# How can I remove duplicate values in a listbox datasource?

Tags: vb.net

Currently working on this small bit of code and was wondering how I could remove duplicates from my listbox. Not sure if using a When statement inside of the query would fix it or not.

```
Public Class frmLab37
    Dim artists() As String
    Const IDX_DATE As Integer = 0
    Const IDX_RANK As Integer = 1
    Const IDX_SONG As Integer = 2
    Const IDX_ARTIST As Integer = 3
    Private Sub frmLab37_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        artists = IO.File.ReadAllLines("BillBoard Hot100 2001 to 2015.csv")
        Dim artistQuery = From people In artists
                          Let year = people.Split(","c)(IDX_DATE)
                          Let rank = people.Split(","c)(IDX_RANK)
                          Let song = people.Split(","c)(IDX_SONG)
                          Let artist = people.Split(","c)(IDX_ARTIST)
                          Order By artist Ascending
                          Select artist
        lstArtists.DataSource = artistQuery.ToList
        lstArtists.SelectedItem = Nothing
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The `ListBox` is irrelevant. You even say in the title that you need to remove duplicates from the data source. It's the data source that matters, i.e. the `List` generated from the LINQ query.

Comment: But is there a way I can remove duplicates in the LINQ Query other than deleting contents inside of the csv file? The expected output result I was given shows no duplicates, and I don't believe that anything was edited in it.

Comment: The whole point of `Let` in a LINQ query is to create a local variable that can be used later in the query so why would you be calling `people.Split(","c)` four times? Use `Let` to assign the result of that call to a local variable and then use that local variable later when you need that result. That said, you're not using `year`, `rank` or `song` anywhere anyway so what's the point of them?

Comment: Forgot to delete those lines before posting this, ended up deleting them after seeing your comment.

Comment: One thing that might be worth considering here is that an artist name or, more likely, a song name could contain a comma. You probably ought to be quoting those values in case they do and then using a CSV reader that will treat quoted values as atomic, e.g. a `TextFieldParser`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is a list of distinct artist values from that list then forget the stuff that isn't the artist. Just get the artist values and call `Distinct`:

```vb
Dim distinctArtists = File.ReadLines(filePath).
                           Select(Function(s) s.Split(","c)(IDX_ARTIST)).
                           Distinct().
                           ToArray()
```

Notice the call to `ReadLines` rather than `ReadAllLines`. `ReadLines` should be the default and you should only use `ReadAllLines` when you need random/multiple access to the resulting array.

EDIT:

I tend to prefer function syntax but, if you prefer query syntax, that would look like this:

```vb
Dim distinctArtists = (From s In File.ReadLines(filePath)
                       Select s.Split(","c)(IDX_ARTIST)
                       Distinct).ToArray()
```

Comment: I have added a second code example that you may prefer.